# with WP8.1, how to send full size photo as attachment using email?

Tags: 8.1, email, photos, attachments

I am trying to send photos as attachments using email (default app) on my WP 8.1 (Lumia 540). It re-sizes files to ~500 KBs (from 7 MB file). I am actually sending these file for printing and these re-sized files will result into bad prints.
I tried hotmail as well gmail accounts, but does same. Also tried to attach photos as files (from files app and from gallery), it still re-sizing files.

Is there any way to send full size photos as attachments from WP.

Note- I was able to send full size photos from outlook app from android phone.

Comment: Does the resizing occurs even when you are connected to a Wi-Fi? If not it may be due to mobile data saving.

Comment: Yes, this happens even with wi-fi

Comment: I have updated to Windows 10 Mobile. This is working with this update.

Comment: You mean your problem got solved with W10 update? Then why not share it and accept it as an answer as other people will get to know this.

Comment: @Kolappan, Yes, problem got solved with W10M. I will add it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation with Windows Phone 8.1.

I have updated to Windows 10 Mobile. Mail client (Outlook) with Windows 10 Mobile is able to send full size photos and other files too. It also supports many more features like text formatting, inset picture, etc.

Comment: You can mark your reply as answer so that this question will be marked as answered (else it will still be left as unanswered). Also change "life" in your answer to "like".

Answer (score 3):

Zip the photos into one .7z archive using `8-zip` and send the archive as attachment....wp might not resize in this case...
You may also try renaming it to .xyz ,so that wp may not try to compress it like it does for photos

Comment: Thanks for work around. This will not display preview of photos and also receiver need to extract the file (one more task).

Comment: have you tried renaming it to .xyz